# How to re-direct to login page from vuex action in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Hi i have a existing project where in all `action.js` we are dispatching `logoutFromServer` upon `401 Unauthorized`

here is how it will look like this

`users.action.js`

```
 async getAllUsers(context,payload={}){
    try{
       let resp = await axios.get(...);
    }catch(error){
       if(error.response.status == 401)
         context.dispatch('logoutFromServer');
    }
 }
```

`customers.action.js`

```
async getAllCustomers(context,payload={}){
    try{
       let resp = await axios.get(...);
    }catch(error){
       if(error.response.status == 401)
         context.dispatch('logoutFromServer');
    }
 }
```

there above code is repeated in almost every `GET,POST,PUT,DELETE` at least more than 1000 places(so i cannot change them now). upon dispatch  of `logoutFromServer` i'm getting

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

**for below code**

`authentication.action.js`

```
 async logoutFromServer(context){
    try{
     let resp = await axios.delete(...);
    }catch(e){
       console.log('must be already deleted');
    }
    //clear cookie 
    this.$router.push({name:"login"})   <-- here the above error occurs i,e  `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')`
 }
```

**Question:** how to re-direct from `vuex actions` to /login route

Please help me thanks in advance !!

Comment: What is Vue version? this.$router is supposed to be there if a store is vue instance but not guaranteed. You can import a router explicitly

Comment: @EstusFlask my vue version is `"vue": "^2.6.14"`  and `vuex` version `"vuex": "^3.6.0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can explicitly import the router and use it.

==> router.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";


Vue.use(VueRouter);

export const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'hash',
    base: "./",
    routes: [
      { path: "/", component: home},
      ...
    ]
})
```

===> actions.js

```
import {router} from "../router.js"

export const someAction = ({commit}) => {
    router.push("/");
}
```